# javascript add dynamical list item left to right then down-- instead of just down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anyone help? I am using this dynamic list item widget http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tzpg4/4/

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
        if( i > 2 ) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

I was wondering how it can be modified so that the list boxes get added left to right and then down -- instead of just down? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add either `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;` to the CSS rule applied to your `<p>` tags.

By default, the `<p>` tag has block formatting. This means that no other elements can flow on the same line.

Comment: Please note that, semantically, the `<p>` tag is probably not meant to be used like this.

Comment: p { padding:0 0 5px 0; float: display: inline-block } I tried this but it did not work.

Comment: `float: display: inline-block` is not valid CSS. Replace with either `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;` only.

Like this: `p { padding:0 0 5px 0; display: inline-block; }`

Comment: BDawg, Thanks for your help. Sorry I messed that up. I have now tried: p { padding:0 0 5px 0; float: left; } and p { padding:0 0 5px 0; display: inline-block; } and the list boxes continue to only go down.

Comment: That's very strange. I tried both on your jsfiddle and it worked. Are you sure you haven't changed something else? Here's what I did: http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/14509/

Comment: Well you have certainly given a correct answer. Why it does not work when I try it is indeed puzzling -- not to mention frustrating. Hopefully, I will figure it out. But thank you nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to BDawg's answer You would want to consider creating a containing div to the size of the menu you want, then use CSS for the positioning on your `<p>` tags, to help ensure no undesired floating.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp